# How to fix "Segmentation Fault" in this case

Tags: c, struct, typedef, strtok

I want to make a program that reads a string with the information of a party, separates the information between "/" and then creates an object with the info.

I made a cicle, as shown in the web. If I just want to print it, it works fine, but when I try to assign it to the variables, the error happens - **Segmentation Fault**

My struct is the following:

```
typedef struct {
  char description[40];
  int date;
  int time;
  int duration;
  int room;
  char parent[40];
  char kids[3][40]
} Party;
```

And the function that reads the string is:

```
void createParty():
  Party p;
  char s[LIMIT] = "John's Birthday/25032019/2230/10/1/Thomas/Anna/Jack/Sarah";
  char c[2] = "c";
  char *token;
  int i=0;

  token = strtok(str, s);

   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s);

      if (i==0)
        strcpy(p.description,token);
      else if (i==1)
        p.date=atoi(token);
      else if (i==2)
        p.time=atoi(token);
      else if (i==3)
        p.duration=atoi(token):
      else if (i==4)
        p.room=atoi(token);
      else if (i==5)
        strcpy(p.parent,token);
      else
        strcpy(p.kids[j-6],token);

      i++
   }
```

I expected that all the values would be assigned with no problems, but when I try to assign the last kid, it gives me the **Segmentation Fault**. If I don't try to assign the last name, there is no errors.

Thanks!

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct {
  char description[40];
  int date;
  int time;
  int duration;
  int room;
  char parent[40];
  char kids[3][40]
} Party;`  1) for flexibility, separate the typedef from the struct definition.  2) most debuggers use the 'struct tag name' to access the fields within the sturct, so need to add a 'tag' name

Comment: regarding: `token = strtok(str, s);`  This is NOT the syntax for `strtok()`  The syntax is: `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`  I.E. the second parameter is a pointer to a char array of delimiters.  (in this case `"/"`

Comment: regarding: `char c[2] = "c";`  this char array is not used.  For clarity, suggest removing that variable declaration

Comment: the posted code contains a logic error.  This statement: `token = strtok(NULL, s);` needs to be at the end of the loop`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates the multiple testing of variable `i`
2. eliminates the use of 'magic' numbers
3. corrects the logic errors
4. corrects the syntax errors
5. assures that char arrays are not overflowed
6. cleanly compiles
7. needs a 'main()`function to call the`createParty()` function
8. properly prototypes the function: `createParty()`
9. defines the struct in a flexible manner
10. defines a 'tag' name so a debugger can loop at the individual fields in the struct
11. separates the 'typedef' from the struct definition
12. allows there to be more than one party, simply by changing the `MAX_PARTIES` to a value other than 1
13. documents why each header file was included
14. uses appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for readability
15. the OPs code called `strtok()` at the top of the loop, so the results from the first call to `strtok()` were printed, but never processed into the struct

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf()
#include <string.h>   // strtok(), strncpy()
#include <stdlib.h>   // atoi()

#define LIMIT          500
#define MAX_PARTIES    1
#define MAX_DESC_LEN   40
#define MAX_PARENT_LEN 40
#define MAX_KIDS       3
#define MAX_KID_LEN    40

struct PARTY
{
  char description[ MAX_DESC_LEN ];
  int date;
  int time;
  int duration;
  int room;
  char parent[ MAX_PARENT_LEN ];
  char kids[ MAX_KIDS ][ MAX_KID_LEN ];  // was missing trailing semicolon 
};
typedef struct PARTY MyParty;

// prototypes
void createParty( void );    //  notice 'void' parameter in prototype


void createParty()           //  removed extranious trailing char
{
    MyParty p[ MAX_PARTIES ]; // Note: a 2 space indent level can be 'lost' with variable width fonts
    char s[LIMIT] = "John's Birthday/25032019/2230/10/1/Thomas/Anna/Jack/Sarah";
    char delimiters[] = "//";  // note using '//' as first slash 'escapes' the second slash
    int i=0;

    char * token = strtok( s, delimiters );

    while( token  && i < 11 ) 
    {
        printf( "%s\n", token );

        switch( i )
        {
            case 0:
                strncpy( p[i].description, token, MAX_DESC_LEN-1 );
                break;

            case 1:
                p[i].date = atoi( token );
                break;

            case 2:
                p[i].time = atoi( token );
                break;

            case 3:
                p[i].date = atoi( token );
                break;

            case 4:
                p[i].duration = atoi( token );
                break;

            case 6:
                p[i].room = atoi( token );
                break;

            case 7:
                strncpy( p[i].parent, token, MAX_PARENT_LEN-1 );
                break;

            case 8:
                strncpy( p[i].kids[0], token, MAX_KID_LEN-1 );
                break;

            case 9:
                strncpy( p[i].kids[1], token, MAX_KID_LEN-1 );
                break;

            case 10:
                strncpy( p[i].kids[2], token, MAX_KID_LEN-1 );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "unexpected field found: %s\n", token );
                break;
        }

        i++;  // was missing trailing semicolon
        token = strtok( NULL, delimiters );  // prep for next loop iteration
    } // end switch
}  // end function: createParty()
```